# Как сделать аббревиатуру из строки?

Tags: delphi

Дана строка: `s:='Вася ест пирог';` Как получить первые буквы этих слов?

Answer (score 1):

Нет под рукой делфей(точно как пишется не помню)
но что то вроде

```
Var
  list:TstringList;
  S:String;
  Result:string;
  i:integer
Begin
  s:='Вася ест пирог';  
  List:=tstringList.Create;
  List.Text:=Replace(S,#32,#13#10);
  for i:=0 to List.Count-1 do
    if (Length(List[i])>0)) then Result:=Result+List[i][1];
  List.free;

end;
```

Comment: Если уж StringList, то он умеет работать с разделителями, в том числе с произвольными. CommaText или DelimitedText, Delimiter, StrictDelimiter. В данном случае:

    Delimiter:=' ';StrictDelimiter:=True;DelimitedText:=S;

Comment: Да, `Replace(S,#32,#13#10)` - брутально.

Answer (score 0):

Отличный велосипед ;)

```
procedure TForm1.MyProc;  
var  
 MyStr: string;  
 result: string;  
begin  
 MyStr:= 'Вася ест пирог';  
 result:= '';  
 while MyStr <> '' do  
  begin  
   result:= result + MyStr[1];  
   if Pos(' ', MyStr) <> 0 then  
    delete(MyStr, 1, Pos(' ', MyStr))  
   else  
    MyStr:= '';  
  end;  
 ShowMessage(result);  
end;
```

Comment: если будет два пробела подряд, то...

Comment: благодарю.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov ну я же сказал, что это велосипед. тем более, что под конкретный вопрос. пример достаточно наглядный, и из него можно сообразить что-нибудь свое.

Comment: Это не велосипед, а самокат, но для д/з на тройку вполне сойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Первые буквы - те, которые стоят сразу после пробела.
<code>

```
program Vasya;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils;
var
  S:String;
  i:Integer;
begin
  ReadLn(S);
  Write(S[1],' ');
  for i:=1 to Length(S) do
    if S[i]=' ' then
      Write(S[i+1],' ');
  WriteLn;
  ReadLn
end.
```

</code>В задаче не говорится, нужно ли пропускать лишние пробелы. Если даже и нужно, это делается вот так:
<code>

```
begin
  ReadLn(S);
  Write(S[1],' ');
  i:=1;
  while i<=Length(S) do
    begin
      if S[i]=' ' then
        if S[i+1]=' ' then
          begin
            inc(i);
            Continue
          end
        else
          Write(S[i+1],' ');
      inc(i)
    end;
  WriteLn;
  ReadLn
end.
```

</code>